# Why does the Next.js `Link` Component add `.txt` at the end of URL when navigating to `href='/'` on GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, github-pages, next.js13

I have deployed my website on github-pages. I am using `Link` Component provided by next to navigate in my website. But when I click the component with the `href="/"` it adds .txt in the end of url. I am using `/app` strucutre

I have an array for the nav items.

```js
const navItems = [
  {
    path: "/",
    
    title: "Home",
  },
  {
    path: "/portfolio",
    title: "Portfolio",
  },
];
```

and I'm iterating through it in the return function

```js
      {navItems.map((item: navItem, index: number) => (
          <Link
            href={item.path}
            key={index}
            className={item.path === currentRoute?.path ? "border-b-2" : "border-transparent border-b-2"}>
            {item.title}
          </Link>
        ))}
```

The problem only exists after deployment and not in development environment
[image: Image of url]

I tried looking in the Next.js docs but couldn't find anything related to this problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Could not find a way to fix it but I did find a workaround.

Add a `/home` page (name it however you want) or something and make it a duplicate of your index `'/'` page.

Then in your `<Link>`, do:

`<Link href={"/home"}>foo</Link>`